# Parent code is called twice in multi process program in C

Tags: c, process, fork

I have been learning about fork in c and i have this program:

```
 int main(void) {
     int i;
     printf("Start program\n");
     printf("This is parent process %d: %d\n", getpid(), i);
     int pid = fork();
     printf("%d ", pid);
     if(pid == 0) {
       printf("This is process %d: %d\n", getpid(), i);
     } 
   return 0;
 }
```

This is the output:

```
Start program
This is parent process 4467: 0
4578 Start program
This is parent process 4467: 0
0 This is process 4578: 0
```

I do not understand why the parent code is called twice.

Comment: Maybe it's the buffer being duplicated before being flushed, and your program runs actually once

Comment: Check if pid is -1.

Answer (score 8):

stdout is buffered. See e.g. [setvbuf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html).

You forgot to call [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) before doing your [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html). As a rule of thumb, you'll better do `fflush(NULL)` before any `fork()`.

That could explain the observed behavior (because flushing happens later in both parent and child processes, e.g. at program exit or return from `main` in [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0)). You might (on Linux) use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand more exactly what is happenning.

BTW,  [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) could fail. You should handle that (that is, handle the `pid == -1`  (or `pid<0`) case...).

Comment: `stdout` is usually line buffered when tied to a terminal or a console. The OP's system seems to set `stdout` to fully buffered, maybe a side effect of running in an IDE or on a legacy system.